# Is it possible to preserve folder window positions in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

When I open a folder in Windows 10, I prefer to have the folder window (not maximized) always at the same position on the screen (near the center). But Windows keeps moving the folder windows when I open and close them, especially after turning the laptop off/on.

Is there a way to make the folder windows always open at the same position, in other words, make them stick to where they are on the screen when opened?

Comment: If this is about Windows Explorer, do you mean opening all Explorer windows, or do you mean that various folders should remember their opening positions? The last one is impossible.

Comment: @harrymc I mean the latter. Various folders should remember their X-Y coordinates on the screen, whenever I open them. If you are perfectly sure it is impossible, and I mean without any third party software, then I can accept it as answer. Though, I would also be interested to know, if it is possible with third party software. Thank you.

Comment: It's possible if it is always the same folders at the same position/size, using third-party software.

Comment: Yes, same folders always at the same position/size. Actually, one single position/size for all folders. Do you know any such software? Thank you.

Comment: xPlorer2 (zabkat) will do this. Folder position and contents are saved and used each time you open xPlorer2.

Comment: @harrymc "I know a  sceret, but I'm not going to tell you"? Which 3rd party softeare, please?

Comment: You get this secret for free (like everything here) : [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). I can help (also for free).

Comment: But Harrymc makes you Beg for it!

Comment: Reported to work in W10, I use it in W7 and works.....https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/shellfolderfix.html

Comment: Originated on this site but you have to become a member to download....https://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html